# How to validate an email that it should contain at least some characters before "@"

Tags: ios, validation, swift4

in my app user can enter his email or phone number. I need to validate wether it's a phone number or email. if email entered it should be validated
ex: if user entered only "@mail.com" need to show not a valid mail to user.there should be at least 2 or three characters front of "@" here is my code

```
func validateEmail(enteredEmail:String) -> Bool {
    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)
    let email = emailPredicate.evaluate(with: enteredEmail)

    if enteredEmail.contains("@") {
        let characters = enteredEmail.components(separatedBy: "@")
        if characters.count > 0 {
            if characters[0].isEmpty {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return email ? email : enteredEmail.count == 10 //if email evaluation is false check for phone number count 
}
```

This code is working fine for me but need a better solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply modify the regex? It already checks if there is *one or more* characters before the `@` character. If you want to check for *two or more* use `{2,}`

```
let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]{2,}@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
```

Apart from the phone validation this is a *swiftier* way to apply the regex

The pattern is

- 2 or more characters from the character set `[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]`
- one `@`
- one or more characters from the character set `[A-Za-z0-9.-]`
- one `.`
- 2-64 upper- or lowercase `alpha` letters

---

```
func validateEmail(enteredEmail:String) -> Bool {
    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]{2,}@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    return enteredEmail.range(of: emailFormat, options: .regularExpression) != nil
}
```

If the entered string must **exactly** match the pattern use

```
let emailFormat = "^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]{2,}@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}$"
```

**Edit:**

To include also the phone validation (just 10 digits) use

```
func validateEmail(enteredEmail:String) -> Bool {
    let emailFormat = "^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]{2,}@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}$"
    guard enteredEmail.range(of: emailFormat, options: .regularExpression) == nil else { return true }
    return enteredEmail.range(of: "^\\d{10}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil
}
```

Comment: My first guess, but i tried removing that validation code in the middle of the method to just use the regex (since he wanted a better solution), and the return statement will be true if the string is longer than 10 characters, regardless of its content.

Comment: Used this but failing at the extent if user entered 10 characters exactly ex: xxxxx@mail

Comment: It fails because the regex checks for the presence of `.` plus extension (`xxxxx@mail.com`). The absolute number of entered characters is irrelevant. I would separate the mail validation from the phone validation anyway.

Comment: Good point, vadian. In my answer I actually separated both validations, and performed them using regexes.

Comment: i mean regex returns true for this "xxxxx@mail" actually it should return false

Comment: The regex is clear. It's supposed to return `false`.  I tested it. Please try my code without any changes.

Comment: @RuslanLeshchenko Is `....` a placeholder or 4 dots? The regex doesn't consider more than one dot. If it's a placeholder please give a real example.

Comment: @vadian It is 4 dots, any count of dots =(

Comment: @vadian Ok, could you please give an entire expression which can check multiple dots before and after @?

Comment: @RuslanLeshchenko Actually the regex considers also `"....@....com"` (I just checked it) unless the dots are not dots but for example a [*horizontal ellipsis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) (`…`)

Comment: @vadian But I use just simple dot from ios keyboard and this "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]{2,}@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}" expression passes "....@....com" email.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. The regex **does** pass  `....@....com`. Do you mean it should not?

Comment: @vadian Sorry, yes, I mean that it shouldn't pass such email.

Comment: To consider only one dot after `@` remove the dot within the brackets. But this will brake subdomains. To return `false` for multiple dots before `@` it's more complicated because you have to add a rule *no consecutive dots*

Comment: @vadian Thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

use **hasPrefix:**

Example:

```
"hello dolly".hasPrefix("hello")  // This will return true
"hello dolly".hasPrefix("abc")    // This will return false
```

That way you can check if the first character is '@' or not and go on from there with an if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

the function is defined properly the issue that will be faced is when user type email like "  @mail.com" as you are not trimming characters before validation.

Your code should be as follows:

```
if enteredEmail.contains("@")
{

    let characters = enteredEmail.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces).components(separatedBy: "@")
    if characters.count > 0 {
        if characters[0] > 2 {
            return true
        }else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The regex he/she posted does not allow spaces.

Comment: `isEmpty` does not trim whitespace from a string so need to remove it before validating the string.

Comment: I agree with you, but that's not the problem he/she is having.

Comment: yes, `if characters[0] > 2` this is the solution to his/her problem but I wanted to drive his/her attention to the problem with white space also.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is fine: the error is in the return statement -and I actually don't like the code in the middle of the method-. You should validate phone numbers with another regex, not just string length, and then drop that if.

Here you have a cleaner example. You should change the phone number regex: it's for Spanish phone numbers.

```
import Foundation

func validateEmail(enteredEmail:String) -> Bool {
    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)
    let email = emailPredicate.evaluate(with: enteredEmail)

    return email
}

func validatePhoneNumber(enteredPhoneNumber:String) -> Bool {
    let phoneFormat = "\\A[0-9]{9}\\z"
    let phonePredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneFormat)
    let phone = phonePredicate.evaluate(with: enteredPhoneNumber)

    return phone
}

func validate(enteredString: String) -> Bool {
    if validateEmail(enteredEmail: enteredString) == true {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return validatePhoneNumber(enteredPhoneNumber: enteredString)
    }
}

validate(enteredString: "@email.com") // false
validate(enteredString: "some@email.com") // true: first regex
validate(enteredString: "666666666") // true: second regex
validate(enteredString: "some rubbish") // false
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code is working fine. an edit Needed in phone number validation because the phone number should be exactly 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
class func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {

        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
    }
```

Comment: That's actually the first three lines of his/her answer.